# How can I crop an image by a filter?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to crop a gray image by a mask. The gray image contains a digit that I want to process further for OCR.

The gray image in the following code snippet is only an excerpt of a bigger image but I took only the relevant part out of it (both for the image and the mask).

I thought that the cv2 function bitwise_and() should do the job, but I am apparently wrong (at least in the way I am doing it).

How can I achieve that my `result` contains these parts of the gray image that represent the digit `5` and all other parts of it are set to `0`? Is this really something that cv2 should do, or is it better to use numpy for that? I have to keep the shades of gray as binarizing it would lead to errors in a further tesseract step.

So effectively it seems that everything equal/below the threshold `133` has to be set to 0.

The result:
[image: screenshot of mask, grayed, and result]

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import cv2

maskString = \
"""
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0
0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0
0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0
0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0
0,2,2,0,0,0,2,2,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0
0,2,2,0,0,0,2,2,0,0
0,2,2,0,0,0,2,2,0,0
0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0
0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
"""
grayedString = \
"""
133,133,133,133,133,133,133,133,133,133
133,132,168,201,201,201,201,185,132,133
133,132,225,232,201,201,201,185,132,133
133,132,247,185,132,132,132,132,132,133
133,142,255,168,132,132,132,132,132,133
133,168,255,159,201,193,151,132,132,133
133,193,255,232,201,217,255,177,132,133
133,168,193,132,132,132,201,255,132,133
133,132,132,132,132,132,168,255,168,133
133,185,168,132,132,132,168,255,151,133
133,217,247,132,132,132,210,247,132,133
133,142,240,232,201,232,255,159,132,133
133,132,142,185,201,185,142,132,132,133
133,133,133,133,133,133,133,133,133,133"""
grayed = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(grayedString), sep=',', header=None).values.astype('uint8')
mask = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(maskString), sep=',', header=None).values.astype('uint8')
result = cv2.bitwise_and(grayed,mask)
```

Comment: Please give a little bit more information about your usecase.

Comment: @MuneebAhmadKhurram: my usecase is that I want to extract digits out of an image for OCR purposes. Presently I have a `mask` that allows me to remove everything from that image that does not relate to the digit. But I cannot use the `mask` itself for OCR purposes, as it is only binary. And I realized that the different shades of gray of the original `grayed` array help to correctly recognize the digit via tesseract.

Comment: You need to use value '255' in your mask as high value, not '2'. The rest looks fine. Curious though, if you already know that the character is a '5' (according to the mask), why do OCR ?

Comment: >>"everything equal/below the threshold 133 has to be set to 0." => use cv.treshold() for that.

Comment: Using `255` instead of `2` did the trick. Thanks a lot. Why I need the OCR? I am processing several images. And the mask is OCRed to a `&`. That's why I need the shades of gray.